# The name of the room holding the Philosopher's/Sorcerer's Stone in first Harry Potter movie/book

Tags: harry-potter, names

In the first book/movie of Harry Potter, he and his friends go to a specific room to get the Sorcerer's Stone.

This room had many traps, like the famous giant witch chess, for example.
We know some things about this room:

- The stone was there;
- Professor Quirrell (and Voldemort) arrived first;
- Professor Dumbledore hid the The Mirror of Erised in this room;

My question is:

What is the name of that room? I don't remember any appearance or even any quote about that room in the rest of the story. Are there some?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown in [Vishvesh's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/108578/31394), the entrance to the rooms (rooms, plural - there are several, listed below) is in a **corridor on the 3rd floor**.

From that corridor, the Trio descend through a trapdoor beneath Fluffy into a series of chambers, known to HP Wikia simply as [the Underground Chambers](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Underground_Chambers). After going through the trapdoor, they have to pass through six more rooms, each with an associated test/task:

- the Devil's Snare room (task associated to the Herbology class)
- the flying-keys room (task associated to the Charms class)
- the chessboard room (task associated to the Transfiguration class)
- the troll room (task associated to the Defence Against the Dark Arts class)
- the logic-puzzle room (task associated to the Potions class)
- the Mirror of Erised room, containing the Philosopher's Stone itself, where Quirrell awaits Harry.

Most or all of these rooms also appear on Pottermore and in the Harry Potter video games, as listed in the table [here](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Underground_Chambers#Behind_the_scenes), but they are never given specific names beyond "the underground chambers".

Answer (score 10):

As Vishvesh says, the trapdoor and Fluffy are located in a corridor. Once they go through the trapdoor, they need to make their way through passageways and through rooms which have the obstacles in them. The rooms themselves don't seem to have names, but Harry refers to "the flying-key room":

> 'No, listen - get back and get Ron - grab brooms from the flying-key room ...'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* - pp.207-8 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 16, *Through the Trapdoor*

And the chessboard is within a room:

> The next chamber was so dark they couldn't see anything at all. But as they stepped into it, light suddenly flooded the room to reveal an astonishing sight.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* - p.204 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 16, *Through the Trapdoor*

What we do know is that the trapdoor gave them access to the dungeons and all of these rooms and passageways were part of Hogwarts' dungeon complex:

> 'What happened down in the dungeons between you and Professor Quirrell is a complete secret, so, naturally, the whole school knows.'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* - p.214 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 17, *The Man with Two Faces*

Comment: Nice find on the Dungeons, clear answer! Well done :)

Comment: Not sure if I agree with your interpretation. "Dungeons" could be a generic word which Dumbledore is using to refer to underground rooms. Is there necessarily a "dungeon complex"? I bet they wouldn't have been able to access the Slytherin common room by walking far enough.

Comment: @randal'thor Given the way Hagrid talks about how Hogwarts is the safest place in the world, and given it's an ancient castle full of magic and secrets, I would say it seems incredibly likely that already existing rooms have been repurposed. It would be my understanding that some of Hogwarts' dungeons were taken over for use in guarding the Philosophers Stone and presumably made secure from the rest. When Dumbledore says 'down in the dungeons' to me that very much suggests that it was part of the generic Hogwarts dungeons, rather than something different or new

Comment: It is true, though, that the word "dungeons" is used rather loosely of Hogwarts, I mean, Snape's classroom may be horrible, but it's clearly not a prison per se

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it was a room, it was a locked corridor. This is mentioned twice.

**First Time:**

> “And finally, I must tell you that this year, the third-floor corridor on the right-hand side is out of bounds to everyone who does not wish to die a very painful death.”
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, Chapter 7, The Sorting Hat*</sup></sub>

**Second time:**

> Harry turned around — and saw, quite clearly, what. For a moment, he was sure he’d walked into a nightmare — this was too much, on top of everything that had happened so far.
>
> They weren’t in a room, as he had supposed. They were in a corridor. The forbidden corridor on the third floor. And now they knew why it was forbidden.
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, Chapter 9, The Midnight Duel*</sup></sub>

Comment: The corridor is only the first of the seven 'rooms'. From the corridor they drop through a trapdoor to access the other rooms and finally the Stone.